# How can I identify record differences between two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two queries. The first query:

```
select in_gentime
from in_time_temp
where cardnumber = 'MCL1570'
order by in_gentime
```

Output is:

```
2011-10-11 08:06:00.000
2011-10-12 08:35:00.000
2011-10-13 08:21:00.000
2011-10-15 08:21:00.000
2011-10-16 08:21:00.000
2011-10-17 08:21:00.000
2011-10-18 08:21:00.000
2011-10-19 08:21:00.000
2011-10-20 08:21:00.000
2011-10-21 08:21:00.000
2011-10-22 08:21:00.000
2011-10-24 08:21:00.000
2011-10-25 08:21:00.000
2011-10-26 09:00:00.000
2011-10-27 09:00:00.000
2011-10-28 09:00:00.000
2011-10-29 09:00:00.000
2011-10-31 09:00:00.000
```

The second query:

```
select out_gentime
from out_time_temp
where cardnumber = 'MCL1570'
order by out_gentime
```

Output is:

```
2011-10-11 22:02:00.000
2011-10-12 21:14:00.000
2011-10-14 21:59:00.000
2011-10-15 21:59:00.000
2011-10-16 21:59:00.000
2011-10-17 21:59:00.000
2011-10-18 21:59:00.000
2011-10-19 21:59:00.000
2011-10-20 21:59:00.000
2011-10-21 21:59:00.000
2011-10-22 21:59:00.000
2011-10-24 21:59:00.000
2011-10-25 21:59:00.000
2011-10-26 18:15:00.000
2011-10-27 18:15:00.000
2011-10-28 18:15:00.000
2011-10-29 23:15:00.000
2011-10-31 22:15:00.000
```

I need to identify records that have `DATE` values that appear in one table but not the other.  I want to ignore the specific `TIME`. For example, I want to only return these 2 records:

```
2011-10-13 08:21:00.000
2011-10-14 21:59:00.000
```

How can I write a query to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what these dates are and how they are related? What is the actual logic behind the desired output?

Comment: Most of your times are not in both tables.  Do you not want the time part considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, you can join together the list of dates and then just pick the records where one or the other is NULL:

```
SELECT COALESCE(i.in_gentime, o.out_gentime)  -- pick first non-null value
FROM in_time_temp i
FULL OUTER JOIN out_time_temp o 
    ON  CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), i.in_gentime,  112) AS datetime) = 
        CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), o.out_gentime, 112) AS datetime)
    AND i.cardnumber = o.cardnumber
WHERE (i.in_gentime is null or o.out_gentime IS NULL)
AND   (i.cardnumber = 'MCL1750' OR o.cardnumber = 'MCL1750')
```

**Update**.  Nathan, here is the full test code, I'm not sure why you are not getting results, but this returns 4 records when I run it:

```
CREATE TABLE in_time_temp  
(
    in_gentime   datetime,
    cardnumber   nvarchar(50)
)
insert into in_time_temp values('2011-10-11 08:06:00.000', 'MCL1750')
insert into in_time_temp values('2011-10-12 08:35:00.000', 'MCL1750')
insert into in_time_temp values('2011-10-13 08:21:00.000', 'MCL1750')
insert into in_time_temp values('2011-10-15 08:21:00.000', 'MCL1750')
insert into in_time_temp values('2011-10-16 08:21:00.000', 'MCL1750')
insert into in_time_temp values('2011-10-17 08:21:00.000', 'MCL1750')


CREATE TABLE out_time_temp
(
    out_gentime    datetime,
    cardnumber   nvarchar(50)
)
insert into out_time_temp values('2011-10-11 22:02:00.000', 'MCL1750')
insert into out_time_temp values('2011-10-12 21:14:00.000', 'MCL1750')
insert into out_time_temp values('2011-10-14 21:59:00.000', 'MCL1750')
insert into out_time_temp values('2011-10-15 21:59:00.000', 'MCL1750')
insert into out_time_temp values('2011-10-16 21:59:00.000', 'MCL1750')
insert into out_time_temp values('2011-10-17 21:59:00.000', 'MCL1750')
insert into out_time_temp values('2011-10-18 21:59:00.000', 'MCL1750')
insert into out_time_temp values('2011-10-19 21:59:00.000', 'MCL1750')


SELECT COALESCE(i.in_gentime, o.out_gentime)  -- pick first non-null value
FROM in_time_temp i
FULL OUTER JOIN out_time_temp o 
    ON  CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), i.in_gentime,  112) AS datetime) = 
        CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), o.out_gentime, 112) AS datetime)
    AND i.cardnumber = o.cardnumber
WHERE (i.in_gentime is null or o.out_gentime IS NULL)
AND   (i.cardnumber = 'MCL1750' OR o.cardnumber = 'MCL1750')
```

And the output is:

```
2011-10-13 08:21:00.000
2011-10-14 21:59:00.000
2011-10-18 21:59:00.000
2011-10-19 21:59:00.000
```

Comment: interesting approach... personally I would check the execution plan of both and see which performs better... I suspect this will be better than my 2 selects with in clauses unioned together.

also my answer would likely perform better if I had used the left join where not null techinique of creating a not in query.  

Excellent answer JohnD

Comment: @jsobo, Definitely he should take a peek at the execution plans.  It looks like there are multiple ways to skin this cat.  :)

Comment: Sorry, looks like I reversed out_time_temp and out_gentime when I did my test -- I just updated the query.

Comment: i run this query select coalesce(i.in_gentime, o.out_gentime)  -- pick first non-null value
from in_time_temp i
full outer join out_time_temp o on cast(CONVERT(varchar(8), i.in_gentime,    112) AS datetime) = 
                                 cast(CONVERT(varchar(8), o.out_gentime, 112) AS datetime)
where i.in_gentime is null or o.out_gentime is null and i.cardnumber = 'MCL1570' and o.cardnumber = 'MCL1750' i didnt get any values...

Comment: This is secanrio,ya,in this two table i need only the missing dates in both tables i.e in_time_temp,out_time_temp..eg Oct,13,2011 record is there in in_time_temp but not in out_time_temp and Oct14,2011 record is there out_time_temp but not in in_time_temp  i need to get this two records alone....

Comment: Nathan, I fixed the query to have the card number

Comment: @JohnD i have run u r query i didnt get any records

Comment: @Nathan, please see the full example, it returns 3 records (10/14, 10/18, 10/19)

Comment: what happen to this record 2011-10-13 08:21:00.000 it should come on it is in in_out_temp table

Comment: my apologies, there was a typo in the cardnumber (I had mcl1570 instead of mcl1750)

Answer (score 2):

something like this...

```
select in_gentime as THETIME from in_time_temp where cardnumber = 'MCL1570' 
 and in_gentime not in 
(select out_gentime from out_time_temp where cardnumber = 'MCL1570')
union
select out_gentime  as THETIME from out_time_temp where cardnumber = 'MCL1570'
 and out_gentime not in 
(select in_gentime as THETIME from in_time_temp where cardnumber = 'MCL1570' )
order by THETIME
```

This should give you all the unique items accross the two tables.

Comment: If i run this query i am getting all the 36 records first table-18 records and second table-18 records  and second table -18 records i want only these two records 2011-10-13 08:21:00.000
2011-10-14 21:59:00.000

Comment: apparently I guessed what you wanted incorrectly.  Do you want the unique values... or the first date that has a non-unique time?  instead of stating what the results should be could you state the RULE and folks could help you write the query.

Comment: ya,in this two table i need only the missing dates in both tables i.e in_time_temp,out_time_temp..eg Oct,13,2011 record is there in in_time_temp but not in out_time_temp and Oct14,2011 record is there out_time_temp but not in in_time_temp  i need to get this two records alone....

Answer (score 1):

This should provide you with the times that are in one of the two tables:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN in_gentime IS NOT NULL THEN in_gentime
          ELSE out_gentime
       END AS THETIME
FROM in_time_temp AS i
FULL OUTER JOIN out_time_temp AS out ON i.cardnumber = out.cardnumber
   AND i.in_gentime = out.out_gentime
WHERE i.in_gentime IS NULL
   OR out.i_gentime IS NULL
order by in_gentime
```

When you want to only reference the `DATE` and not `TIME` portion, that answer is here (much like what JohnD has provided as well, biggest difference is my use of `CASE` and his (probably more efficient) use of `COALESCE`)

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN i.in_gentime IS NOT NULL THEN i.in_gentime
          ELSE o.out_gentime
       END AS THETIME
FROM in_time_temp AS i
FULL OUTER JOIN out_time_temp AS o ON i.cardnumber = o.cardnumber
   AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), i.in_gentime, 112) AS DATETIME) =
      CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), o.out_gentime, 112) AS DATETIME)
WHERE i.in_gentime IS NULL
   OR o.out_gentime IS NULL
order by i.in_gentime
```

Comment: i want to company month,day,year also....then only i will get that two records and based on the card number

Comment: @Nathan I have added an option to only bring back records based on date.

Answer (score 0):

```
select in_gentime
from in_time_temp
where cardnumber = 'MCL1570' and
      dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, in_gentime), 0) not in
        (select dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, out_gentime), 0)
         from out_time_temp 
         where cardnumber = 'MCL1570')
union all         
select out_gentime
from out_time_temp
where  cardnumber = 'MCL1570' and
      dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, out_gentime), 0) not in
        (select dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, in_gentime), 0)
         from in_time_temp 
         where cardnumber = 'MCL1570')
```

Comment: i am getting all the records i need only that two records 2011-10-13 08:21:00.000 2011-10-14 21:59:00.000 is possible

Comment: @You have to explain the logic behind that. Why not 2011-10-18 21:59:00.000 and 
2011-10-19 21:59:00.000

Comment: @Nathan What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: THANKS A LOT IT IS POSSIBLE TO GET THE TIME

Comment: it is possible to get the time also

Comment: here time comes as 00:00:00.000